# PHP's date usage results in 2 hours error

Tags: php

I'm using `date('H:i:s', (time() - $start['time']))` to displa time that passed since start of the script.

whatever the result of `time() - $start['time']` - be it 0, 17 or whatever the date prints out like 02:00:00, 02:00:17 etc.

What may be the reason?

Comment: Hard to say without you telling us how you set $start['time']

Comment: So where does $start['time'] come from? And why aren't you simply using microtime()?

Comment: Where do you start `$start['time']`

Comment: Check your timezone setting, or set one if you haven't with [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://us2.php.net/date_default_timezone_set)

Answer (score 1):

`time` returns an **absolute** numeric timestamp, say the numeric value for `2012-06-04 16:35:12`. Your start time is a similar numeric, absolute timestamp. Subtracting one from the other will result in a very small number, which is, again, an absolute timestamp. Likely some time around the beginning of 1970. When you format that timestamp using `date('H:i:s')`, you only display the time portion of a timestamp like `1970-01-01 02:00:00`.

Read about what [UNIX timestamps actually represent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp).

The time difference that you're looking for is the result of `time() - $start['time']`, which is in seconds, which you can't simply format using `date()`. More along the lines of:

```
$diff = time() - $start['time'];
echo 'Difference in seconds: ' . $diff;
echo 'Difference in minutes: ' . $diff / 60;
echo 'Difference in hours: '   . $diff / 60 / 60;
```

Comment: Well actually it does not really matter since he only displays the hours, minutes and seconds. If he is not interested in the absolute date there is no problem with that.

Comment: Treating a relative timestamp delta as absolute timestamp which depends on timezone settings etc. will always be problematic. Time deltas and absolute timestamps simply aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

seems you have a 2H offset added.

```
// save current TZ
$current_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
// Use universal time
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$t = time();
echo "T:".$t."<br/>";
sleep(2);
echo "T2: ".date('H:i:s', time() - $t );
// return correct TZ
date_default_timezone_set($current_tz);
```

If i try this code without the date_default_timezone_set('UTC') it gives me expected value + 1H from Summer Time (GMT+1). If you only need the diference between the 2 times you can use UTC for both and you only get the diference OR you can check the current time offset and subtract it.

Hope it helps